# How do I display an image in a razor view in a ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I don't have much experience with ASP.NET, I'm trying to display an image called 'HighRes.jpg' 2000 times. The image is located in the same folder as the razor view.I can't get the image to load, am I missing something? Here is the code:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@model float
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "asp";
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style.css">
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 10px;
        }

        .grid-item {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>

    @{
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
    <div class="grid-container">
        @for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            <div class="grid-item">
                <img src="~/HighRes.jpg" alt="HighRes"/>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @{
        stopwatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        double memoryUsed = (double)GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024);
    }
    <p>Elapsed time: @elapsedTime ms</p>
    <p>Memory used: @memoryUsed MB</p>
</body>
```

I tried displaying an image 2000 times inside an HTML grid in an ASP.NET MVC razor view. The image is not loading and I do not know why.

Comment: What happens if you just type `http://localhost:<your_port>/HighRes.jpg` into your browser?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd it says "This localhost page can’t be found"

Comment: The image should be inside the `wwwroot` folder and you need to call `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Program.cs`. Check [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Moving the image to the wwwroot folder worked.

Answer (score 1):

The image should be inside the `wwwroot` folder and make sure that you call `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Program.cs`. Check [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

> The image is located in the same folder as the razor view. I can't get
> the image to load, am I missing something?

Actually, if your image would serve out side of your wwwroot folder in that scenario `src="~/HighRes.jpg"` would not able to load your image accordingly because while image located out side of  wwwroot  we need [StaticFiles Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) within program.cs file while for wwwroot  it doesn't require.

Let's have a look in practice. Assume, you have following directory:

[image]

Thus, based on above directory you should write following code snippet within your program.cs file if you would like to load your image out side of wwwroot  in this scenario

[image]

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ImagesOutsideRoot")),
    RequestPath = "/ImagesOutsideRoot"
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="~/ImagesOutsideRoot/HighRes.jpg" alt="HighRes" />
</div>
```

However, if you want to load image from inside your wwwroot folder in that scenario, you would only need `app.UseStaticFiles();` in program.cs and Following html:

[image]

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="~/Images/HighRes.jpg" alt="HighRes" />
</div>
```

**Note:** As I am keeping the picture inside Images folder so I use `~/Images/` but if you just keep it inside wwwroot you would write `src="~/HighRes.jpg"`

Output:

[image]

**Note:**

As per your scenario, it would then load your image accordingly. For more details and example please [have a look our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)